# How to wait for the GPU to finish its work in DirectX9?

Tags: directx-9

I'm looking for a method to wait for the GPU to finish its work in DirectX9. Something equivalent to the `glFinish` command in OpenGL...

I already know that it's not something I should do, but I have to! I'm writing a threaded Graphics Engine integrated in WPF and I need to make sort of an off-screen rendering in order to give a valid surface to a D3DImage. The frames are very long to compute (more than 100ms) and the rendering of the WPF Image sometimes occurs while the frame is not fully computed by my Engine even if I lock everything the right way. I'm almost sure it's just a Finish issue but I didn't find out how to do that.

So far, I tried to launch a DX9 query like this :

```
using namespace SlimDX.Direct3D9;

public class GraphicsDevice: Device
{
    ...

    public void Finish()
    {
        var query = new Query(this, QueryType.Event);
        EndScene();
        while (!query.CheckStatus(true)) ;
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to work...

So, first question without talking about WPF, do you know how to wait for the GPU to finish what has been sent to the driver?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a so complicated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution.
I was not aware that it actually work!

I used an EventQuery to 'mark' my last call to the GPU.
Then I put some kind of infinite loop flushing the GPU instructions and waiting for the EventQuery to be finally fired by the GPU, using the GetData/CheckStatus methods.

Comment: Can you edit and provide your updated code in your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes! I'll do it in a few days, when I have time.